# Many to many with Multiple primary keys?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, join

Situation:

TableParent with 2 primaryKeys, ParentKey1 and ParentKey2
TableChild with 1 primaryKey, ChildKey
TableConnector with columns ParentKey1, ParentKey2 and ChildKey

This is where I think I should go with my Linq query. Notice I'm fetching all childs belonging to a parent so I have it's keys as parameters.

```
var query = from conn in db.TableConnector
            join child in db.TableChild on conn.ChildKey equals child.childKey
            join par in db.TableParent on conn.ParentKey1 equals par.parentkey1 into connGroup
            from co in connGroup
            where co.ParentKey1 == Parameter1
            Select child;
```

Well I tthink this works up to a point, let's say if parent had only one key, am I right?

I guess I have to join some more into a second group but I'm currently lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have two primary keys on your table.  You can only have one primary key (hence the name primary).  It sounds like you have a *composite* primary key, which means a key that is composed of more than one column.

I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve, but it seems to be retrieving all TableChild rows for a given TableParent key.  It should be something like this:

```
db.TableParent
    .Single(parent => parent.ParentKey1 == key1 && parent.ParentKey2 == key2)
    .TableConnectors.Select(connector => connector.TableChild)
```

If you have your tables mapped correctly on your Linq-to-Sql designer then you don't have to manually join them - that's what the Linq-to-Sql code generation does for you.

For example, when you have a `TableConnector` you will be able to retrieve the `TableChild` rows for it using something like this

```
TableConnector t = db.TableConnectors.First();
List<TableChilds> tableChilds = tableConnector.TableChilds.ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah I meant composite primary key as there are two columns defining the primary key. As I mentioned SQL isn't my strong suit. I'm gonna check this solution out. I'm sure it works but I'm also curious about how to do it with the same type of query as I am doing as that could help me with the SQL itself.

Comment: Sorry I'm not really into the 'query' syntax, I find it very unintuitive and I'm a bit tired to translate it accurately.  But the crux is that you don't have to manually join up the tables - that's what the LINQ-to-SQL code is doing for you.

Comment: Trying your former solution I get an error "Type argument cannot be inferred from usage". Isn't the SelectMany gonna return TableConnector objects instead of TableChild objects? Just taking selects instead of selectMany is error free. Also can I wrap in in a object somehow? like old query type "select new wrapper( child );"

Comment: Yes you're right, I don't know why I put SelectMany - should definitely be Select.  I'm not sure what you mean by wrapping it in an object - what do you want to return from the query?  What object would you wrap the result in?

Comment: .Select(connector => new Wrapper( connector.TableChild )); This worked for the wrapping. The case is I don't use the object plainly as it comes from Linq-to-sql and also not adding methods through the partial class for some reason so I wrap it in my own better defined class. It's constructor takes this linq entity object as a parameter. Might not be a great solution but it works for me :)

Comment: Sure - you can do that if you want, as long as `Wrapper` has a constructor that takes a `TableChild`.

Comment: Yeah you are right, was editing my comment when you posted yours, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

tableParent only needs one primary key (it's own Id) and tableChild needs one (it's Id)
the connectorTable only needs two columns to make the many-to-many-relation work:
ParentId and ChildId

For each relation between a parent and a child you simply add one row to the connectorTable, and in order to retrieve the results try this:

```
select * from tableParent
inner join connectorTable
on tableParent.Id = connectorTable.ParentId
inner join tableChild
on connectorTable.ChildId = tableChild.Id
```

If your reason for multiple keys in the parent table is that you want to create relations between parents as well this needs to be addressed either via a relation field in the parent table (one-to-many) or another relationTable (many-to-many)

Comment: I think the TableParent table has two columns in its primary key.

Comment: but the example only uses one to filter the query (where co.ParentKey1 == Parameter1)

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't clear but Kirk Broadhurst is right. The parentTable ahs 2 primaryKeys and I have both parameters. I just wasn't sure how to add the later one. That's why I marked parameter1 as there is also parameter2.